# Solution of $a f'(x) + b f(x) + \exp(c f(x)) = w$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck with a differential equation of the following form:
\begin{equation}
a f'(x) + b f(x) + \exp(c f(x)) = w
\end{equation}
where $a,b,c,w$ are constants.

Is there a closed form solution to this type of differential equation? If yes, how can it be solved, is there any good reference for a specific solution technique?

Thanks, Chris

Comment: Consider function $x(f)$ instead

Comment: @YuriyS. For sure ... but what about the monster ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I'm afraid I do not understand what you mean. Unless you are talking about the resulting integral

Comment: @YuriyS. Yes, this is he point.

Comment: Yes, no closed form for the integral

Comment: I was very surprised when $y''+e^y=0$ turned out to have a closed form solution. This one seems unlikely to have it. But it is still considered exactly solvable because $x(f)$ is explicitly represented by an indefinite integral

Comment: @YuriyS I don't quite get it. Can you please give some more details

Comment: This equation is fully separable. Bring everything but the derivative to the right hand side, and then consider $f$ the independent variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to explain the comments from Yuriy and Claude Leibovici :
$$a \frac{df}{dx} + b f + \exp(c f) = w$$
$$\frac{dx}{df}=\frac{a}{- b f - \exp(c f) + w}$$
$$x=a\int \frac{df}{- b f - \exp(c f) + w}+\text{constant}$$
This is the solution implicitly expressed on the form of a function defined by an integral.

As far as I know, there is no closed form for this kind of integral.

A-fortiori, the inverse function $f(x)$ cannot be expressed with a finite number of standard functions.

Approximate solution can be expected on the form of finite series or more likely in practice thanks to numerical calculus.

Answer (score 2):

You can linearize the equation with $c \lll 1$. Then $e^{cf} \to 1 + cf$, and the integral becomes

$$ x(f) = \int \frac{a}{(w-1) - (b+c)f}df = -\frac{a}{b+c}\big[\ln \big|(w-1)-(b+c)f\big|- \ln k\big] $$

Then
$$ f(x) = \frac{(w-1) - k\exp\big(-\frac{b+c}{a}x\big)}{b+c} $$

This is the best I can get to a "closed form"